# How do I invoke Link Update Mode in the Plaid Sandbox Quickstart app (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, sandbox, multi-factor-authentication, plaid

I have the Plaid Quickstart (node) up and running.

I successfully logged in to one of the sandbox institutions (First Platypus Bank) using the sandbox credentials and got the access_token which it generated.

Per the Link Update Mode docs (https://plaid.com/docs/link/update-mode/), you should be able to "force a given Item into an ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED state".

From the docs I linked to above...

> Update mode can be tested in the Sandbox using the /sandbox/item/reset_login endpoint, which will force a given Item into an ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED state.

I used Postman (in the Sandbox Public environment) to send an API call to this endpoint, https://sandbox.plaid.com/sandbox/item/reset_login, to force the ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED state.

This is the body sent with the API call...

```
{
  "client_id": "{{client_id}}",
  "secret": "{{secret_key}}",
  "client_name": "Insert Client name here",
  "country_codes": ["US"],
  "language": "en",
  "user": {
  "client_user_id": "unique_user_id"
},
  "access_token": "{{access_token}}"
}
```

This is the response I got back...

```
{
  "expiration": "2021-02-13T04:13:12Z",
  "link_token": "link-sandbox-7d82e9b8-b8a7-4977-9c20-aadbc82ec050",
  "request_id": "eE56J8f5XJKpS6L"
}
```

...which is what I expected.

I then went back in to the Quickstart app and logged in to the "First Platypus Bank" again expecting to be prompted for the MFA challenges, but, instead, it just created a new access_token.

So, how to I get the Plaid Quickstart app into Link Update mode?

**Update:**

Per Alex's question, here is an image showing the Postman call I made. He's correct, it was a /link/token/create call. What's confusing it that it's labeled **Create Link Token - Update Mode**.

[image: Postman]

**Update 2:**

Here's the  /sandbox/item/reset_login call and response. There's no link_token included in the response.

[image: Postman 2]

**Update 3:**

Between Alex's help and some help from Plaid support, I got this working.

I was putting the link token in the wrong place.

For anyone seeing this in the future, here are the steps you need to follow to get the node quickstart app into Link Update Mode.

You can also watch [this video](https://youtu.be/4e1vk4qrPKI) to see a demo of the process; HOWEVER, note that in the video, I put the link_token in the wrong place. The instructions below show how to put it in the correct place.

- Get the access_token for the institution you want to get into Link Update Mode (this assumes you have the quickstart app installed, up and running. See... https://plaid.com/docs/quickstart/)

  - Start the quickstart backend (/quickstart/node/start.sh)
  - Start the quickstart frontend (cd /quickstart/frontend; npm start;)
  - Once the frontend fires up on port 3000 in your browser, click the "Launch Link" button then click "Continue".
  - Search for the institution (e.g., First Platypus Bank, First Gingham Credit Union...if in sandbox mode. or your own institution if in dev mode)
  - Enter your credentials (user_good/pass_good ...if in sandbox mode)
  - Copy the access_token
  - Close the Plaid browser tab
- In Postman (to set this up, see... https://github.com/plaid/plaid-postman), enter the access token you just copied into the access_token variable (See the first screenshot above. Click on the icon near the upper right-hand side that looks like an eye then scroll down to access_token and enter it.)

  - Run the /sandbox/item/reset_login endpoint. It's labeled "Simulate ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED [Sandbox only]" in Postman. The request body should look like second screenshot above. Once you Send the request, the response body should show `"reset_login": true`. Now the Plaid Item (i.e., the institution) is in ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED mode.
  - Run the /link/token/create endpoint. It's labeled "Create Link Token - Update Mode" in Postman. The request body should look like the first screenshot above. Once you Send the request, the response body should give you a link_token. Copy it for the next step.
- Put the link_token in the Plaid quickstart app.

  - On [line 23](https://github.com/plaid/quickstart/blob/master/frontend/src/App.tsx#L23) in /quickstart/frontend/src/App.tsx, replace `data.link_token` with your link_token. So this `dispatch({ type: "SET_STATE", state: { linkToken: data.link_token } });` becomes this `dispatch({ type: "SET_STATE", state: { linkToken: "link-sandbox-704ef648-2acd-44a2-867b-ea1258e9205c" } });` (Use your own link_token, of course, and don't forget the quotes around your link_token.)
- Restart the backend and frontend. When you launch Link, it should now be in Link Update Mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process you describe sounds right, but the API request and response bodies in your post are the request and response for /link/token/create, not /sandbox/item/reset_login.  Can you verify that you didn't accidentally call /link/token/create instead of calling /sandbox/item/reset_login?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, you're correct. I did a /link/token/create call. It's confusing though because in Postman, it's labeled Create Link Token - Update Mode (see image above). I'll try the reset_login and report back.

Comment: I did the  /sandbox/item/reset_login call (see Update 2 above). There's no link_token in the response. I figured, maybe in the sandbox it, somehow, automatically puts it in Link Update mode after the  /sandbox/item/reset_login call so I logged back in to First Platypus Bank (expecting it to go into Link Update mode) and it, instead, created a new access_token. Hence, my confusion. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'll create a task to clarify the flows in the Postman Collection.  Anyway, after calling /sandbox/item/reset_login, you need to pass the access_token it returns as a parameter to /link/token/create (you can use the Create Link Token - Update Mode Postman request, just make sure to copy + paste the access_token into line 10 of the request).  When you initialize Link with the link_token returned by that call, Link will open in Update Mode.

Comment: Still can't get this to work. I feel like we're maybe getting our wires crossed so I created a screencast to show you exactly what I'm doing [link](https://youtu.be/4e1vk4qrPKI). A couple things to note: 1) Maybe I'm not putting the link_token in the right place in the quickstart app [link](https://github.com/plaid/quickstart/blob/master/frontend/src/Context/index.tsx#L15), 2) You'll notice when I go back to the terminal the second time there are some warnings there (from the compiler, I suppose). Are they of any concern?

Comment: Alex, I've been having a conversation with Plaid support about this. I think I may be putting the link_token in the wrong place. I won't have time to test it until later today, but wanted to let you know so you don't spend any more time on this unnecessarily. I appreciate your taking the time you already have. I'll report back once I've had a chance to do more testing.

Comment: That was the last piece of the puzzle! It's working now. Thanks for your help, Alex. You pointed me in the right direction. I'll update my original question and mark yours as the accepted answer.